Combinatorial Game: If Bob takes the arithmetic mean and Alice the geometric mean, can Bob achieve $1012$?
I came up with the following problem:

Alice and Bob have written all numbers from $1$ to $2024$ in a blackboard and they are going to play a game. In each turn Alice can remove two numbers and write their geometric mean on the board and Bob, in his turn, can remove two numbers and write their arithmetic mean. If Alice starts playing, can Bob devise a strategy such that the last number remaining is greater than $1012$ regardless of how Alice plays?


I tried finding an invariant so I considered $\sigma_n$ and $\pi_n$, the sum and product of all numbers after turn $n$, respectively. Notice that $\sigma_{2023} = \pi_{2023}$ and, if $(x_i, x'_i)$ are the pair of numbers chosen on turn $i$, \begin{equation} \sigma_{2i} = \sigma_{2i-1} - \frac{1}{2}(x_{2i}+x'_{2i}) \\ \sigma_{2i+1} = \sigma_{2i} - x_{2i+1}-x'_{2i+1}+ \sqrt{x_{2i+1}x'_{2i+1}} \\ \pi_{2i+1} = \frac{\pi_{2i}}{\sqrt{x_{2i+1}x'_{2i+1}}} \\ \pi_{2i} = \frac{\pi_{2i-1}(x_{2i}+x'_{2i})}{2x_{2i}x'_{2i}} \end{equation} Since this formulas are recursive we can conclude $$\sigma_{2023}= s_0 - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{1011}(x_{2i}+x'_{2i})-\sum_{i=0}^{1011}(x_{2i+1}+x'_{2i+1}-\sqrt{x_{2i+1}x'_{2i+1}})$$ and something similar holds for $\pi_{2023}$. The best greedy algorithm I can think of is Bob always choosing the smallest pair of numbers and Alice the biggest pair; however, with this algorithm Bob can win and this isn't optimal for Alice. After checking with a Python simulation, I found out that Alice does have a strategy to beat Bob if he always chooses the smallest pair but I am not sure if Bob can find an even better strategy to counter Alice.
I would appreaciate any help on finding the solution, thanks beforehand.

Please identify the source of the problem.

@quasi, I invented the problem

Why 2024?${}{}{}$

Because we are in $2024$, there is no specific reason. For small $n<13$ I have computed with Python that Bob can actually win. There is a slight difference between odd and even cases but nothing major.

If the optimal strategies for small $n$ already appear to require a computer program to fully describe them, why would you expect otherwise for $n=2024$?

Maybe there is a solution which doesn't require a computer simulation, I don't know if Bob's strategy of choosing the smallest pair is actually the best. I am asking to see if anyone can come up with a better strategy or provide a counterexample without a computer.

ea, I think the greedy algorithm for Alice is choosing the largest & smallest number and remove them...?

I would guess Alice wants to pick the largest and smallest numbers available.  The geometric mean is as far from the top number as possible.

@RossMillikan, I simulated that strategy for Alice and it isn't optimal either, Bob gets to win by choosing the smallest pair of numbers. Actually, it is worse for Alice than choosing the largest pair of numbers each time.

I believe a better strategy for Bob is to choose a pair $(a,b)$ minimizing $(a+b)/2-\sqrt{ab}$, so choosing $a, b$ close and big. And a better strategy for Alice would be to "break" the good pairs of vertices, maybe by following the same strategy as Bob (or a 1 look-ahead strategy)

@RossMillikan if Alice has number $a \ll b \approx c$, and she chooses $a, c$ she leaves $\sqrt{ac}, b$. If she chooses $b, c$ she leaves $a, \sqrt{bc} \approx b$. So she is better choosing larger numbers.
